# How to convert an HTML website to Drupal 7 nodes?

Tags: nodes, theming

I have a website that I want to move to Drupal 7. It is in HTML. I want the content to be in nodes. I don't know much about Drupal and so I need help doing this. I don't want to create a new theme because I want the design to change. I just want the content in nodes. How can I do this in Drupal? Is there a module that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a module to add a content to drupal. Just simply create a content of type page and add your content. To help you with formatting, you may want to install the [WYSIWYG](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module to help you with formatting.

Comment: For some reason I can't find the option to create a new page.

Comment: Can you see content on your menu?

Comment: I see content but when I click it there is nowhere to add a new page

Comment: At the top left you would see add content. Click on it and then choose basic page

Comment: It takes me to Add Project page when I do that and the option for basic page is not shown

Comment: go back to your homepage, and at the end of the url add node/add

Comment: It forwards to upload project. Is this right?

Comment: better you install a new drupal site and add the contents by using ths url node/add

Answer (score 1):

The module I used (several years ago) was the [Import HTML](https://drupal.org/project/import_html) module. I imported a site into Drupal 5 and it worked well. There is a Drupal 7 dev version, but I have no experience with it.

If you use it, plan and prepare well, and you can expect a considerable amount of manual editing after the fact. You may have to try a few times before you get it right, but for a bulk import, it saved me a lot of work.