# Is it possible and reasonable to convert a complicated, heavily styled html page into an editable Drupal site page?

Tags: nodes, theming, migrations

I already read this:

[How to convert an HTML website to Drupal 7 nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74917/how-to-convert-an-html-website-to-drupal-7-nodes)

and this:

https://www.drupal.org/node/313510

and some more.

Hello,

I have been tasked with creating an editable version of an html page that is heavily based on this template's design:

http://themeforest.net/item/zayra-bootstrap-3-retina-app-landing-page-/full_screen_preview/8135956

http://themeforest.net/item/zayra-bootstrap-3-retina-app-landing-page-/8135956

(not trying to advertise, just to give an idea)

I have read and learned about Drupal in the past week and have reached the point where I feel comfortable:

1. Tweaking themes.
2. Adding articles, polls and such plain content.
3. Messing around with the admin panel.

I don't understand how one would add content that is less "straight forward" to a Drupal site. Is it reasonable to do? Can it be done more easily with other CMSs (like Wordpress)? Should I tell my boss that the CMS should be used for news and articles in other areas of the site but *NOT* this specific promotional page?

From what I read I realize that I could create a rather complex view and a gazillion nodes and use that to generate an editable promotional page that looks like this template. My concern is that it may turn out unfriendly to the content professional.

I really would like to hear some expertly advice on how reasonably doable the task of creating an editable version of the promotional html page is in Drupal (that looks like the original).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use drupal to develop and complexity of site including that of a complex css design.  I personally work for a digital agency and every single project I have been on has been built in drupal and has been heavily design oriented.  I have also built JS apps in drupal as well.

If you are looking for a theme out of the box then you probably wont find it as they are generally free and not a whole lot of design into them.  If you are comfortable or willing to learn to create your own theme and template files then you most certainly can do this inside drupal.

It all depends on your level of knowledge and effort.

Here are a few heavy sites designed in drupal:

http://www.elmwoodreclaimedtimber.com/virtual-showroom (js app, but the site is also built on drupal)

http://www.servicesource.com

http://www.jedunn.com

http://www.tnvacation.com/made-in-tennessee

With drupal you have CSS, PHP, and MYSQL which means you can do anything those technologies can.

EDIT***

Also to answer your question more specific it really depends on how much of the content will be editable.  Drupal provides a more flexible GUI type layout called panels and panelyzer that provides more of what you may need.  Research into Panopoly distribution as its geared more towards landing pages

Comment: How would a page like http://www.servicesource.com look to the content editor? How does the editing form look for pages that are made of multiple different parts?
Thanks for taking the time to answer the question and show these brilliant examples. I think by the second one I was convinced that I could learn and accomplish what this company requires for the homepage look.

Comment: The content on these usually consisted of simple basic pages content types with custom themes.  Generally the markup is created first and then we create the theme inside drupal using a custom theme templates.  If we need content or CMS content that is editable we either create these as separate content types and use entity reference to tie them together.  Then views displays the data.  A lot of this content on the service source site is simply a basic page with blocks as HTML.  Not saying these sites are easy to do but def possible.

Comment: As far as service source.  The home page consists of a slider content type that is set using the Context module, then the arrows and other content is actually just blocks of HTML with JS in our custom theme.  The other pages with filters are used with views

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about custom themes, there is nothing out of the box. As far as I understand, you need to figure out which CMS is better for your design. I am a big Drupal fan, BUT for small personal projects I'd rather use WP. For my clients' projects that don't involve a huge complexity I also use WP. On the other hand, for small projects that don't require tons of CSS, I use Drupal. It is safer and gives me better perspectives. Your one page theme could be done easily with Drupal, but it does require a bit of javascript - for that you may need to write your own modules.

Regardless design, there is a saying: **the shortest road is the road you know better**.

It isn't a matter of design, it is a matter of purpose & know-how. Choose carefully!

BUT, it really depends on your project's purpose as well. Could be a theme that you want to sell, or a presentation website for a client. That I do not know.

If someone would implement the javascript part, I'd probably code the CSS for that particular design, in Drupal or Wordpress, in one day. I'm not promoting myself, I just give you an example.

Bottom line here: if that was a presentation one-page theme for a customer, I'd use WP. If there are major structural requirement and a multi-page theme with a few projected content types, I'd use Drupal.

Comment: I think you understand correctly but what most interests me is how is editing form going to look and how to make it good ux wise for the content editors that fill in the texts.